# Non-fixed-size Fenwick Tree implementation

Tags: java, data-structures, associative-array, fenwick-tree

I'm planning to implement a non-fixed-size [Fenwick tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree) in Java. That is, a Fenwick tree that allows interleaving range queries with adding/removing elements.

All [implementations](https://sites.google.com/site/indy256/algo/fenwick_tree_extended) and [samples](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Fenwick_tree) I've seen so far are for fixed-size Fenwick trees, where the number of elements is known before preprocessing the frequencies. They use a fixed size array, so it's not possible to add or remove elements after preprocessing is done. (Well, it is possible, but I'd need to re-build the structure).

I thought of extending `TreeMap` or maybe `AbstractMap`, but as `TreeMap` is actually a red-black tree, I don't know how to implement the red-black mechanics (so that the tree remains balanced) without loosing the cumulative sums of nodes involved in the rebalancing process.

So I thought that maybe I should take another approach: why not extend or adapt a simple random access `ArrayList` and re-calculate all cumulative sums when the underlying array is resized? This would of course have an impact but, hey, that's exactly what a `HashMap`does.

This is why I wanted to ask here first, in case someone has already done it, and to check which approach you think is the best.

Comment: @Bohemian, could you please explain how this question asks for a book, tool, software library, tutorial, or other off-site resource?

Comment: @Magnamag Try programmers.stackexchange.com. The problem I have with it is the opening sentence "I'd like to know if there exists a non-fixed-size implementation for Fenwick trees." which to me is asking is there's a library out there

Comment: There is an implementation in C++ of a data structure with your needs: https://github.com/hyPiRion/roulette-tree